# How to fix "ERROR: Invalid id_token. OpenSSL unable to verify data"

Tags: azure, openssl, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to set up my new website with Azure Active Directory SSO. I have registered my app in Azure Active Directory. My website is WordPress-based, so I am using this plugin: https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress

As far as I see, I have set up everything according to the documentation, but I continue to get the following error:

> ERROR: Invalid id_token. OpenSSL unable to verify data:
>   error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid
>   padding

I have been reading and reading in the Azure documentation, but I cannot find any answers. What is the source to this error?

The website is hosted in Azure App Service.

Comment: Error message indicates issues with validating id_token. Suggestions: **1)** Review that all values provided in `3. Configure the plugin` https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress#3-configure-the-plugin are correct ones (i.e. display name of org, clientID, client Secret key and reply url). **2)** Try adding `aadsso_reload_openid_config=1` to query string in login page, as described here https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress#refreshing-the-openid-connect-configuration-cache

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. I have cheked these things again but unfortunately it was all right.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: The app was registered under the "Enterprise applications"-blade in Azure which does not work with the https://github.com/psignoret/aad-sso-wordpress plugin. The app should be registered under the "App registrations"-blade or the "App registrations (Preview)"-blade in Azure.